# Error while inserting data to the mySQL DB, with Java

Tags: java, mysql, exception, insert

Good night everyone. I have these codes. I only copied here the codes which have the problem.

```
//This is my main method. I called my Database.class, made the connection and called the insertnewcustomer method.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Database db = new Database();
    db.connectDB();
    db.insertNewCustomer(86754312, "arda", "zenci", 55418, 400);
.................//

//and here is my insertNewCustomer method which is inside the Database.class

public void insertNewCustomer(int num, String name, String surname, int phone, int debt){
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Customer(customer_cardno, customer_name, customer_sirname, customer_phone, debt) VALUES(" + num + ", " + name  + ", " + surname + ", " + phone + ", " + debt + ")");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

I cannot see any problems but I have a MySQLSyntaxErrorException

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'arda' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
at Database.insertNewCustomer(Database.java:39)
at mainFrame.main(mainFrame.java:50)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you need to surround variables which are not integers with quotes, otherwise database would understand them as column, simply add quotes in not integers column, such as

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Customer(customer_cardno, customer_name, customer_sirname, customer_phone, debt) VALUES(" + num + ", '" + name  + "', '" + surname + "', " + phone + ", " + debt + ")");
```

I assumed `customer_cardno`, `customer_phone`, `debt` being i tegers columns, if they are nit just surround variabkes with quotes

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, **SQL Injection risk**. I suggest you take a look on Prepared Statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Now, if you insist in building the query string like that, you should enclose the `String` values you are inserting in quotes:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Customer " + 
    (customer_cardno, customer_name, customer_sirname, customer_phone, debt) " + 
    VALUES(" + num + ", '" + name  + "', '" + surname + "', '" + phone + "', " + debt + ")");
/*
 * Notice the single quotes arround "name", "surname" and "phone"
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, before you answer, I had found. =)  Thanks again.

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar Anyway, please read the link I provided to you. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Prepared statements can save you a lot of pain (and they are quite easy to use)